# Ticker labels after plot

Tags: label, pine-script

I would really appreciate some help adding a ticker label after my plot from the code below. Below is an extract of the main code - I've only used the lines for 1 ticker but in reality, I'll have 32 symbols in total so I've omitted the unnecessary code duplication for the other tickers for the purposes of this query.

Any improvements on the rest of the code would also be appreciated. I'm using ticker.new as 1) I don't need the inputs and the plot only seemed to display properly when the session was listed as extended (even though the chart was already set to extended)

```
//@version=5
indicator('NASDAQ Trend', overlay=true)

// SYMBOLS // 
s01 = ticker.new("NASDAQ", "AAL", session.extended)

// CALCULATIONS //
screener_func() =>
    //STACKED EMAs
    MA1 = ta.ema(close, 5)
    MA2 = ta.ema(close, 8)
    MA3 = ta.ema(close, 13)
    MA4 = ta.ema(close, 21)
    MA5 = ta.ema(close, 34)
    MA_Stack_Up = (MA1 > MA2) and (MA2 > MA3) and (MA3 > MA4) and (MA4 > MA5)
    
    //CONDITIONS
    Uptrend = MA_Stack_Up
    Reversal = ((MA1 < MA2) and (MA2 > MA3)) or ((MA1 > MA2) and (MA2 < MA3))
    
    //COLOR CODING
    Bar_Color = Uptrend ? color.new(color.green, 25) : Reversal ? color.new(color.yellow, 25) : color.new(color.red, 25)
    
    [Bar_Color]

// Security call
[TS01]= request.security(s01, timeframe.period, screener_func())

// PLOTS //
l_width = 3
shape = plot.style_circles
plot(1, color=TS01, style=shape, linewidth=l_width)

//LABELS//
L1= label.new(bar_index, 1, text=s01, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), size=size.small)
label.delete(L1[1])
```

My problem is the resulting label is ={"session":"extended","symbol":"NASDAQ:AAL"}. Ideally, the label should be just AAL

Comment: It looks like you have a label already. What is the issue with that one?

Comment: My problem is the resulting label is ={"session":"extended","symbol":"NASDAQ:AAL"}. Ideally, the label should be just AAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that extracts the part you are interested from that string. If your string ALWAYS has the same format `={"session":"extended","symbol":"NASDAQ:AAL"}`.

**Step 1:** Split the string using `:` as a delimeter. You will then have 4 sub strings.

- `={"session"`
- `"extended","symbol"`
- `"NASDAQ`
- `AAL"}`  <-- This is what you want (index: 3)

**Step 2:** Remove the last two chars. Since the last two chars will always be `"}`,  return a string until last two chars.

```
getName(_str) =>
    string[] _pair = str.split(_str, ":")
    string[] _chars = str.split(array.get(_pair, 3), "")  // Index 3
    int _len = array.size(_chars) - 2  // Don't get the last two chars
    string[] _substr = array.new_string(0)
    _substr := array.slice(_chars, 0, _len)
    string _return = array.join(_substr, "")
```

Then call this function when you create a label:

```
//LABELS//
L1= label.new(bar_index, 1, text=getName(s01), style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), size=size.small)
label.delete(L1[1])
```

[image]

Comment: Superstar! Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

No sense in doing all those string gymnastics when the ticker is available.    Try this:

```
//@version=5
indicator('NASDAQ Trend', overlay=true)

// CALCULATIONS // {
// hey look – it's now foldable....
screener_func() =>
    // STACKED EMAs
    MA1 = ta.ema(close, 5)
    MA2 = ta.ema(close, 8)
    MA3 = ta.ema(close, 13)
    MA4 = ta.ema(close, 21)
    MA5 = ta.ema(close, 34)

    // CONDITIONS - no sense in allocating extra variables when hidden in function
    Uptrend = (MA1 > MA2) and (MA2 > MA3) and (MA3 > MA4) and (MA4 > MA5)
    Reversal = ((MA1 < MA2) and (MA2 > MA3)) or ((MA1 > MA2) and (MA2 < MA3))
    
    // DETERMINE COLOR CODING - just return the results 
    // vs assigning to a variable and then return the variable...
    [Uptrend ? color.new(color.green, 25) : Reversal ? color.new(color.yellow, 25) : color.new(color.red, 25)]
    
// }

// Define tickers and set up labels on last bar
// Note: request security limits the max number of tickers to 40
var tickers  = array.from("AA","AAL","AAPL")

// use the index of the symbol in the ticker array as price level to plot...
if barstate.islast
    for item in tickers
        label.new(bar_index+ 5, array.indexof(tickers,item), item, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), size=size.small)

// Since the ticker symbol must be know at complile time aka simple string,
// we have to call each symbol separately - what a pain...

// style variations here in case we want to change
var aStyle = plot.style_circles
var aLinewidth = 3

// AA  <-- Yep this is definitely not NASDAQ material...
temp1 = ticker.new("NYSE", "AA", session.extended)
[temp2] = request.security(temp1, timeframe.period, screener_func())
plot(0, color= temp2, style=aStyle, linewidth=aLinewidth)
    
// AAL
temp3 = ticker.new("NASDAQ", "AAL", session.extended)
[temp4] = request.security(temp3, timeframe.period, screener_func())
plot(1, color= temp4, style=aStyle, linewidth=aLinewidth)
    
// AAPL
temp5 = ticker.new("NASDAQ", "AAPL", session.extended)
[temp6] = request.security(temp5, timeframe.period, screener_func())
plot(2, color= temp6, style=aStyle, linewidth=aLinewidth)
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8oAM.png)

Comment: You'll need to add a routine to delete all the labels and then add them back as if the chart is left open, they will draw over themselves....  see the reference manual for label.all for such a routine...